# How to split a list into chunks using recursion?

Tags: python, slice

THere are a list with increased int, i wanna to spilt it into chunks by step, like this:

```py
for i in range(0, len(intlist), length):
    chunks.append(intlist[i, i+length])
```

but each list in chunks have to match `list[-1] - list[0] < 20`. If it don't match, then try `chunks.append(intlist[i, i+length-1])`

for example:

```
chunks = []
intlist = [2, 4, 5, 18, 23, 24, 67, 72, 77, 83, 84, 90]  # item keep increase
for i in range(0, len(intlist), 4):
    chunks.append(intlist[i:i+4])
# output
# item in chunks
[2, 4, 5, 18]  # step 4 match
[23, 24]  # 67-23>20 don't mach
[67, 72, 77, 84] # match
[90]
```

specially, the len(i) must less than argument length, it can't be too long

Comment: What do you mean chunks? Can you give an example of your input list and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: I don't understand what `chunks.append(i, i+length)` is supposed to do. It's not valid and I can't work out what you really mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion for this task. You can simply iterate through the list and keep comparing the current item to the first item of the last chunk, and append a new sub-list if the difference is greater than or equal to 20 or if the last chunk has reached your maximum chunk size:

```
intlist = [2, 4, 5, 18, 23, 24, 67, 72, 77, 83, 84, 90]
chunks = []
for i in intlist:
    if not chunks or i - chunks[-1][0] >= 20 or len(chunks[-1]) == 4:
        chunks.append([])
    chunks[-1].append(i)
```

`chunks` becomes:

```
[[2, 4, 5, 18], [23, 24], [67, 72, 77, 83], [84, 90]]
```

Comment: thanks. i've edit the question. Good answers, but the len of the item in output may too long

Comment: when the lenth become 10 or more, item of chunks: item[-1] - item[0] will more than 20

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: input = [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 25, 30...] the len of chunks item is dymanic, sometimes the len is 4 or 6, others, but item[-1] - item[0] < 20 must match

Comment: And the output would be `[[1, 2, 5, 8], [9, 13, 15, 18], [20, 22, 25, 30]]`. What's wrong with that output?

Comment: Ah, I see that you want to compare the current item to the first item of the last chunk, rather than the last item of the last chunk. Got it.

Comment: By the way, what's your expected output for the input `[1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 25, 30]`?

Comment: it just a sample input, your answer work! thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well your question but here is a one line that can probably fix your problem.
Hope this is it!

```
int_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,8,45,2,1,43,6,7,3]
chunks_size = 4
chuncks = [int_list[chunks_size*i:chunks_size*(i+1)] for i in range(int(len(int_list) / chunks_size) + 1)]
```